# Postgresql : how to transform some columns to a json object?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following results from an inner join query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.label, t2.id, t2.city, t2.ppl 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.country_id
```

| t1.id | t1.label | t2.id | t2.city | t2.ppl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | 1 | Paris | 10800000 |
| 1 | France | 2 | Lyon | 522000 |
| 1 | France | 3 | Marseille | 870000 |
| 2 | England | 4 | London | 9000000 |
| 2 | England | 5 | Liverpool | 500000 |
| 2 | England | 6 | Manchester | 552000 |

1. How to transform the 2nd part to a jsonb column as follows :

| t1.id | t1.label | t2.myjsonb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | [{"Paris" : "10800000","Lyon" : "522000","Marseille " : "870000"}] |
| 1 | England | [{"London" : "9000000","Liverpool " : "500000","Manchester " : "552000"}] |

2. Or How to transform the 2nd part to a jsonb column as follows :

| t1.id | t1.label | t2.myjsonb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | [{"city":"Paris", "ppl": "10800000"},{"city":"Lyon", "ppl" : "522000"},{"city":"Marseille", "ppl" : "870000"}] |
| 1 | England | [{"city":"London", "ppl" : "9000000"} ,{"city":"Liverpool", "ppl" : "500000"},{"city":"Manchester" , "ppl": "552000"}] |

How to do it with Postgresql query ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the SQL query you used to create the join relation, please?

Comment: Use `jsonb_agg` either with a subquery instead of the join or with a `GROUP BY` on the join

Answer (score 1):

With an `INNER JOIN`, you won't get any result for table1 where no corresponding table2 rows exist. A `LEFT JOIN` could fix this, but I think a subquery is simpler:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.label, (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(t2.city, t2.ppl))
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.country_id = t1.id
) AS myjsonb
FROM table1 t1;
```

Notice that `jsonb_agg` returns `NULL` for an empty result, not `[]`. To avoid this, you can use

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.label, COALESCE((
  SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(t2.city, t2.ppl))
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.country_id = t1.id
), '[]'::jsonb) AS myjsonb
FROM table1 t1;
```

or

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.label, to_jsonb(ARRAY(
  SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(t2.city, t2.ppl))
  FROM table2 t2
  WHERE t2.country_id = t1.id
)) AS myjsonb
FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question to see if it could be possible to get another kind of results with a json data. Thanks !

Comment: @toch Please read the documentation on `jsonb_build_object` and try something yourself. If you can't get it to work, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing your approach